# How to properly convert wei to Ether in a contact?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

As we know msg.value in contract is in wei. I wondered if there is a better way to convert it to Ether than dividing it by 10^18?

As an application consider the case where people buy tokens and the contract has a token balance. In this case, if we just copy user payments to the token balance array then the value will be too big and not user-friendly.

Comment: I don't think there is any other alternative. I did not understand your case. But there shouldn't be an issue in diving the value by 10^18, as there are no decimals.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Assume the contract receives 4 ether, which is 4x10^18 wei. I'd like the contract to store 4 in the token balance instead of 4x10^18.

Comment: Okay. So in this case, the only option you have is to divide the no by 10^18. If I find anything I'll update.

Comment: @AdrianAd Dividing the number by 10^18 is the only way to convert it to Ether, because the very definition of Ether is 10^18 wei. Usually, the user interface will do the conversion instead of the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `msg.value` is in wei ( the smallest unit), so you need to explicitly convert it to ethers by diving by 10^18.

Contracts should store balances in `wei` (to avoid division and rounding inaccuracies).

The client can specify the `uint` of value send in a transaction, if not specified it's in `wei`. I don't understand your use case completely but if you could take care of this client side, it will be a better approach. Else you are only left with the option of dividing the number by 10^18.

Ideally, you should implement the token balances in the smallest unit. Like if someone sends you 4 ethers and you store 4 tokens as his balance, but what if someone sends 0.01 ether(10^16 wei), how will you store them? So better go by storing the smallest unit.

Comment: To verify, when i use `eth.getBalance(eth.defaultAccount)` and it returns `1.4428126245294e+22` are you saying this is a value in wei? Why 10^22?  What about when I do `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` it returns `gasUsed: 180457`. This is also wei? All numeric values in geth using eth are in wei?

Comment: No.. Not all numeric values are in Wei. Balance is in wei. But `gas` has no unit, `gasPrice` has, which is again in wei (if not specified).

Comment: Right. Gas and gasUsed are just units. But why even though I’ve been mining on my private network for a while is the balance only 1.4428126224529e+22 wei? If you convert it to ETH it’s basically nothing.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons. Better ask a new question with more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity doesn't store decimals, so you're best off storing in wei and converting to ether on the front end GUI.

That said, if you do have some other valid reason to convert to ether, there is an 'ether' keyword in solidity, so rather than using 10^18, you can do:

```
etherValue = weiValue/(1 ether)
```